# What is Java 8 functional way to implement switch-like construction without "switch" and "if" statements using only java.util

Tags: java, functional-programming

I wrote next code without using if statements and creating own functional API.
And it checks some condition.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String smth = new Random().nextBoolean() ? "something" : null;

        Optional.ofNullable(smth)
                .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
                .<Runnable>map(i -> () -> System.out.println("Success " + i))
                .orElse(() -> System.out.println("error"))
                .run();
    }
}
```

How can I implement `switch` statement using only `java.util.*`?

Comment: That is the strangest looking if - else I have ever seen :)

Comment: Whats your point of filter and map if you only have one value and not a list in the first place??

Comment: Is this a genuine question? You want to use optionals and streams to replace all if statements and switch statements?

Comment: Is this possible?  Yes, it’s possible.  Should you do this?  No, you should not.  Don’t punish other developers with elaborate “tricks” like this.  Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistic:

```
new Runnable[] {
    () -> System.out.println("0"),
    () -> System.out.println("1"),
    () -> System.out.println("2")
}[i].run();
```

Already useful:

```
Map<String, Runnable> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Runnable>builder()
    .put("0", () -> System.out.println("0"))
    .put("1", () -> System.out.println("1"))
    .build();
map.getOrDefault("2", () -> System.out.println("rest")).run();
```

However for playing with functional style programming, better try a really functional programming language.

Comment: That's what I would say too, try Scala instead of trying to write everything functionally in Java.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand thanks for emphasizing that functional programming is best done in an other (more) functional language, as for instance java streams are relatively poor in this respect. Scala is great where it not for some beginner-unfriendly API flexibility. One of my candidates for a java successor.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming there's a tight relationship with `pattern matching` and I guess that you want to achieve exactly that. As of this moment, such feature is not supported out of the box with the standard Java 8. It is, however already debated how it could be implemented in the future - have a look [at the document from Brian Goetz](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html).

In the meantime you could have a look at this [blog](http://www.baeldung.com/vavr-pattern-matching), it utilizes VAVR, a library that facilitates pattern matching. So in your case it would look like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String smth = new Random().nextBoolean() ? "something" : null;

        String result = Match(smth).of(
            Case($(isNull()), "Success " + smth), 
            Case($(isNotNull()), "error"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[JMPL](https://github.com/klappdev/jpml) is simple java library, which could emulate some of the features pattern matching, using Java 8 features.
This library support many patterns, which could see in many languages, such C#, Scala, Rust, Swift.

```
    matches(data).as(
      new Person("man"),    () ->  System.out.println("man");
      new Person("woman"),  () ->  System.out.println("woman");
      new Person("child"),  () ->  System.out.println("child");        
      Null.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Null value "),
      Else.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Default value: " + data)
   );


   matches(data).as(
      Integer.class, i  -> { System.out.println(i * i); },
      Byte.class,    b  -> { System.out.println(b * b); },
      Long.class,    l  -> { System.out.println(l * l); },
      String.class,  s  -> { System.out.println(s * s); },
      Null.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Null value "); },
      Else.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Default value: " + data); }
   );

   matches(figure).as(
      Rectangle.class, (int w, int h) -> System.out.println("square: " + (w * h)),
      Circle.class,    (int r)        -> System.out.println("square: " + (2 * Math.PI * r)),
      Else.class,      ()             -> System.out.println("Default square: " + 0)
   );
```